# C++ const object's member can be modified

Tags: c++, constants

In this code the object bar is an const type, but through the const function I still can modify the member x's value. Is that unreasonable?

the output is

15
25

```
// overloading members on constness
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    int x;
  public:
    MyClass(int val) : x(val) {}
    int& get() const {return x;}
    int& get() {return x;}
};

int main() {
  MyClass foo (10);
  const MyClass bar (20);
  foo.get() = 15;         
  bar.get() = 25;        
  cout << foo.get() << '\n';
  cout << bar.get() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code shouldnt even compile. You cant take a `T&` reference to a `const T` object (which x actually becomes).

Comment: 'get() const' is saying that the function doesn't modify the data (which it doesn't) - not that the return value is const

Comment: @Paranaix but it success to compile

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: yes but eventually the return value that is foo.x is modified. but the foo is constant object, I think all its non-static member shouldn't be changed @Rob

Comment: @Jianchen Then your compiler is bad, this code is definitely not standart conform. See also: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/276401ea448ab055

Comment: I use g++ in jgrasp to compile @0x499602D2

Comment: You are returning a reference to an int and then assigning it. i.e. you are writing something specifically to get around the const protection.

Comment: @Rob Thats clear, but the problem here is that its (actually) not possible to take a modifyable reference to a const object.

Comment: I see. The x here is implicitly type of const int, which cannot be converted to int&. You are right my compiler is bad, it give me warning but still let me run the code @Paranaix

Comment: @Paranaix what you are saying is it is illegal to call any member function on a const object that returns a non-const pointer. That cannot be true (as the compiler has no way of telling if the pointer is in the class or not)... although the compiler could have been more useful here.

Comment: @Rob No, I never said that. But I said that its illegal to take a regular reference to a const object. And if you do `return x;` thats exactly what happens. If you write however `int x2; return x2;` the code is totally legit in terms of constness and typesafety (, yes I know its UB if you access the reference...).

Comment: @Rob: It's not accurate to say "get() const' is saying that the function doesn't modify the data". `get() const` is saying that this particular definition of the `get()` member function applies to `const` objects. Such objects may have `mutable` members and the `get()` member function is free to modify them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int& get() const {return x;}
```

is returning a non-`const` reference to a member of a `const` object. (We know that `*this` is `const` because of the declaration of `int& get()` as `const`.) That should be flagged as an error, since it is an invalid conversion (`x` is not declared `mutable`); both gcc and clang will do so. The fact that your compiler only produced a warning is odd, but nonetheless you should heed the warning.

You could avoid the error by explicitly using `const_cast<int&>(x)`, but it would be undefined behaviour (UB) to attempt to use the returned `int&` to modify `x`. However, the compiler is not obliged to flag as error or even detect all possible expressions which might produce undefined behaviour.

In short, you're allowed to shoot yourself in the foot, but a good compiler will at least warn you before you do that. Listen to the warnings.

Comment: That's not really true in this case. The compiler should produce an error.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes, you are right. I deleted my comment before you posted yours.