# Is it UB to change a member of a const object via a constructor-bound reference?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, language-lawyer

In short: Does the following code have Undefined Behavior, or is this fine?

```
struct X
{
  X(int b)
    : value(b)
    , ref(value)
  {
  }

  int value;
  int& ref;

  void isThisUB() const
  {
    ref = 1;
  }
};

int main()
{
  const X x(2);
  // Is either of these fine?
  x.isThisUB();
  x.ref = 3;
  return x.value;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1TE9a7M4a

`X::value` is const for `x`. According to my understanding of const semantics, this means that modifying it in any way is UB. Yet we can take a non-const reference to it in the constructor and then modify it through that, either in a `const` member function or directly.

The C++ (at least 17) standard gives an example of const-related UB in [[dcl.type.cv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.cv#4) that looks mostly the same, except it employs `const_cast`. Note how `p->x.j = 99` is denoted as UB. I do not see a fundamental difference between achieving this with `const_cast` vs my above code.

So, is the code above UB? Are non-const reference members/pointers really this big of a footgun?

*(If you can come up with search keywords that yield a related question and not just random `const` stuff, I'll be mighty impressed.)*

Comment: This is more of an opinion, but I think this is fine. The `const` on a method is a bit different than a really `const` variable (this is a relevant difference to the standard example you linked). The `const` on a method just forbids certain operations, but does not guarantee that your object is not modified. For example the reference could also be form outside of the class and be passed as a non-const reference argument to the const method. I only see a problem if the member `value` was `const`.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21653460/580083.

Comment: Modifying `const` object is UB.

Comment: [dcl.type.cv/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4.sentence-1): _Any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior._ Isn't this exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Reference members are a footgun imo,  it's too annoying trying to manage their lifetimes and they interfere with objects' value semantics.

Comment: C++17 [dcl.type.cv] uses wrong formatting when saying «`const` object», the correct is to say «const object». And link https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.type.qualifier#def:object,const. Which is what C++20 does.

Comment: spot by gcc/clang in constexpr context [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M6TYT64xb).

Answer (score 4):

> Does the following code have Undefined Behavior, or is this fine?

It has UB. Standard says:

> [dcl.type.cv]
>
> Except that any class member declared mutable can be modified, **any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime results in undefined behavior**.

`x` is const and you modify its non-mutable member.

> I do not see a fundamental difference between achieving this with const_cast vs my above code.

Indeed. Both are UB for the same reason.

> Are non-const reference members/pointers really this big of a footgun?

The trigger for the footgun is the issue that the object is temporarily non-const while it is within its constructor. Hence pointers and references to non-const "this" and its subobjects are readily available wthin the constructor regardless of whether the object is going to be const or not. Thus we can conclude that storing those pointers/references for later use is ill-advised.

Storing pointers and references as members referring to "this" are a footgun for several other reasons as well. They require storage that's otherwise unnecessary if you were to access the referred member through its name directly. Furthermore, you'll find that the copy-semantics of the class will likely not be what you had in mind.

If you want to point to a member out of several alternatives, then use a member-pointer, not an object pointer / reference (using storage cannot be avoided for such case). This solves both copying and accidental const violation.